# maximum number of apples covered

Tags: graph-algorithm

there is a matrix with  apple(one apple only) placed in it at some points.source and destination points are given.We have to find a path starting from source to destination  which has maximum number of apples.

What should be the approach or algorithm to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by using [dynamic programming .](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)

create 2-D array where `DP[i][j] finds maximum apples you can get from (0,0) to (i,j)` .
Now , suppose you are travelling in right or down direction , so from `(i,j)` you can move to `(i+1,j)` or `(i,j+1)` .

`recurrence relation` : `dp[i][j] = max(dp[i-1][j] , dp[i][j-1])  [for i,j = 1 to n-1]`.

you need to track base conditions also when `i=0` or `j=0`.
finally `dp[n-1][n-1]` gives maximum apples .

Time complexity : `O(n*n)` as well as space complexity .
But we can optimize for space as we need to only look for previous row `(i-1)` for current row : `i` . So, space can be brought down to `O(n)` .

Hope it helps you !

Comment: hi thanks for you reply.in my case the direction can be up down left right .will that be solvable through dynamic programming.

Comment: Yes , suppose you want to go to (i,j) , you can come to (i,j) from (i+1,j) , (i,j+1) , (i-1,j) , (i,j-1) . so you can modify accordingly .you can find more about dynamic programming at http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=dynProg&module=Static .    you can accept and upvote my answer if you find it correct .